# PHP7.4で Deprecated: Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored in hexdec

Tags: php

PHP7.4で　下記エラーメッセージが表示されるのですが、どういう意味ですか？

> Deprecated: Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored in hexdec
> Deprecated: Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored in

下記コード辺りに問題があるようにも思われのですが、どう修正すればよいですか？

```
$rgb["red"] = hexdec(substr($colorcode, 0, 2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今回に限らないですが、まずはエラーメッセージや関数名で検索しましょう。

`hexdec` の引数に16進数を表す値以外を渡した場合に表示される警告のようです。

[hexdec](https://man.plustar.jp/php/function.hexdec.html)

> `hexdec()` は、16 進数以外の文字を一切無視します。 PHP 7.4.0 以降では、無効な文字を与えることは推奨されません。
>
> **変更履歴**
>
> | バージョン | 説明 |
> | --- | --- |
> | 7.4.0 | 無効な文字を与えると、非推奨の警告が出るようになりました。 結果は不正な文字がなかったかのように計算されます。 |

[How to Convert a Hexadecimal String to an Integer in PHP?](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-in-php)

通常の使い方:

> ```php
> var_dump(hexdec('4D2')); // int(12345)
> var_dump(hexdec('04D2')); // int(12345)
> var_dump(hexdec('0x4D2')); // int(12345)
> var_dump(hexdec('0x04D2')); // int(12345)
> ```

誤った引数を渡した場合:

> ```php
> // Deprecated: Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored
> var_dump(hexdec('foobar'));
> ```